# How to watch videos in UK from somewhere else?

Tags: proxy, video-streaming

I want to stream the [highlights of NFL](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/nfl/index.html) but I need an UK/Irish IP-Address to watch the video. I have tried with proxies (I managed sometime ago to get the BBC iPlayer working) but they are very slow and I still get the error that I'm not in the right country.

In short: I'm looking for a British proxy server with video support or some other way to get around the ridiculous IP block.

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you running?

Comment: 12.04 LTS Precise

Comment: Close Voters:  The OP is running 12.04, so this is On-Topic.

Comment: @Mitch still OT. He's looking for proxies/VPN. For that there's Super User. If he had problems setting up the proxy *in Ubuntu* then the history is different. Also, as you can see for the answers they are not Ubuntu oriented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use a VPN service which provides UK based IP-addresses. There are some free VPN providers (like [vpnbook](http://www.vpnbook.com) or [VPNreactor](http://www.vpnreactor.com/) and google for others), but you are better off with a pay-for service as those are more reliable and aren't that expensive at all, just google for some.

Comment: vpnbook did the trick! Thanx

Answer (score 1):

You can either buy VPN [here](http://www.hidemyass.com/vpn/) Or you can use web proxies which ever is suitable for you [here](https://hidemyass.com/proxy-list/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Tor browser. Its safe and untraceable and it'll run on a base of firefox. 
You can download it from [here](http://www.torproject.org.in/download/download-easy.html.en), it is by far the easiest and fastest way to go along.